# Can't go to masterpage link in Site Setting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

First, I am not referring to the link to the MasterPage gallery, I can get there just fine. The link I am referring to is under look and feel (when publishing Feature is activated).

I can navigate almost everywhere on the site. The account I am using is added to user policy with Full Control, it is a site collection admin and it is granted Full control on the web level.

I have confirmed that all masterpages have "published" versions (XX.0).

My client originally called with the fact that only non-admin users could access the site, Admin users were not granted access. I resolved that (not 100% sure how it resolved, but by investigating, it started to work)

I don't have any insight into when or how this occurred. The reported symptom was that they disable the Minimal Download strategy feature and it "broke"

Does anyone have any additional thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue with MDS, MDS has nothing with permissions.

In your situation, i think it is better if you get the ULS logs during the issue. why site admin getting the access denied on master page settings page.

Sometime, publishing feature cause this issue, deactivate and reactivate fix this issue.this situation i experienced long time ago.

Comment: ULS logs did not provide anymore insight. Ended up recreating the site.